# Can CSS traverse up the tree to the parent of a clicked element and get the parent sibling?

Tags: css, sass, less, postcss

**I have the following code:**

```
<div class="someClass">
    <input class="myInput"/>
</div>
<div>
    <ul class="myList">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is change a property on the `<ul>` when `input:focus`

Possible or not possible? Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Not possible. It's the old parent selector question.

Comment: not with CSS, is with js

Comment: Thanks for weighing in.